# (Ionic - Firebase) Why only the last data is diplayed?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

**Issue**

I'm using Ionic & Firebase for develop the application.

I don't know why but only the last data added to the database is displayed.

I've tried to use "value" instead of "child_added" but I got a list with only the raw values {"data":"Hello"}

I'd like to get a list with only the values !

Thanks for your help

**news.html**

```
<ion-view title="News">
 <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
  <button ng-click="messageCreator()" class="button button-icon ion-ios-chatboxes-outline"></button>
 </ion-nav-buttons>

 <ion-content class="has-header">
  <ion-list ng-controller="displayMessages">
   <ion-item ng-click="goCalendar()" ng-repeat="val in value"  class="item item-icon-right">
    {{val}}
     <a class="icon icon-accessory ion-chevron-right"></a>
   </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Method for create a new data**

```
$scope.messageCreator = function () {
  $ionicPopup.prompt({
    title: 'New message',
  }).then(function(res) {
      firebase.database().ref('ParentName').push().set({
        data: res
      }).then(function() {
         alert("Data submitted");
      }).catch(function(error) {
        alert(error.message);
     });
  });
}
```

**Method for display data**

```
$scope.displayMessages = function ($timeout) {
  var testRef = firebase.database().ref('ParentName');

  testRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    $timeout(function () {
      update(snapshot);  
    });
  });

  function update (snapshot) {
    $scope.value = snapshot.val();
  }
}
```

**Display only the last data added to the database**

[image: Only last data added]

Comment: up to the list...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any reason for this:

```
testRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
  $timeout(function () {
    update(snapshot);  
  });
});
```

The problem is the type of the data. You should declare your data as an Observable, so that the refresh is instant without the need of extra code. The declaration is like this:

```
data: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
```

This type can be included by:

```
import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
```

You can check a ready tutorial [here](https://github.com/Temeteron/ionic2-firebase-starter-kit), which also provides a live example to test it.

Comment: This is in TypeScript, no...?
How do the same in Javascript please ?

Comment: Yes, this is typescript. Why do you need Javascript, if you are using Ionic typescript is default. The import is the same in Javascript (ES6). You can declare the data in Js like: var data = FirebaseListObservable[]; . I am not really sure if this will work. But in the first place you should use typescript as recommended from Ionic

Comment: Actually, thanks to you, I started learn TypeScript & I restarted my project... It'll be better ^^

Comment: Typescript is really simple i think. I learned Ts when i started using Ionic. Best of luck!